# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager" not found

Tags: php, html, sql-server, xampp, composer-php

I try to host website on xampp , but when I try to open it is just shows me the `login.php` page then no  thing , so I try to check the `config.php` it's gives me an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager" not found in C:\PHP-Projects\obm1\config.php

My database is MSSQL.
I need helpe

also how can I delete composer from my device?

Comment: Can you share more details, like the code involved? Is this really a HTML problem, or one related to [tag:sql-server] or [tag:composer-php]?

Comment: From experience but also from the small amount of details, it looks like `config.php` or another file that's loaded in it is trying to use the `Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager` class.
For anyone stumbling upon this question: just make sure you `use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;` in the correct place.
`